# Docker container hangs in status Created

Tags: linux, docker

In an ubuntu terminal, I run:

```
sudo strace -f -p `pidof containerd` -o strafce_log
```

In another temrinal I run

```
docker run ubuntu
```

The result, both terminals hang :(
If I stop the docker service, then I cannot start it anymore

The container stays in status `created`, and any command I issue against it hangs (`docker logs`, `docker rm`, `system prune`)

Docker commands against other containers or images works fine. Docker ps also works

I also found online that i should look at `cat /var/log/syslog | grep docker`. Unfortunately nothing over there neither.

Can you guide me on where i could get more logs or some info on what is docker or that container doing?

Comment: Does docker hang when you use strace witout -f?

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/issues/1025?

Comment: it works! I have no clue why, but it works :D  Please make it an answer so I can upvote. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, but what have you done - removed `-f` or applied the kernel patch from https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/issues/1025#issuecomment-249074073?

Comment: I have removed -f. the command does not hang anymore, but it produced no output actually :( i will try with the patch now

Comment: FYI, I can reproduce it locally

Comment: I can also reproduce it with a little Go program that someone has posted on the GH site I linked to above

Comment: and with a custom C program also with Linux 5.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analysis of logs produced by `sudo strace -ff -p $(pidof containerd) -o strace_log` shows that it stalls when `execve()` is called by a
process named `runc init`.  This led me to [this bug report on runc GH
page](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/issues/1025) that
explains that it's a kernel bug that can be reproduced with every
program that uses pthreads and `execve()` and presents a short Go
program that can be used to reproduce the problem:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    syscall.Exec("/bin/echo", []string{"/bin/echo", "Hello"}, os.Environ())
}
```

Knowing it's a kernel bug I used Raspberry Pi for testing so that I
could build and replace Linux kernel quickly without risking making my
main machine unbootable or playing around with virtual machines and as
Go is not installed by default in Raspbian I used the following C
program for testing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void *foo(void *p)
{
  (void) p;
  while(1)
    {
      puts("in thread");
      sleep(2);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
  printf("pid: %jd\n", (intmax_t) getpid());
  pthread_t tid;
  pthread_create(&tid, NULL, foo, NULL);

  char *envp[] = {"var"};
  char *ls_args[] = { "/bin/ls" , "-l", NULL};
  if (execve(ls_args[0], ls_args, envp) < 0) {    
    perror("execve error");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Build with `gcc strace-test.c -o strace-test -pthread` and see that
`strace -f ./strace-test` gets stuck as well.

[Patch that was supposed to fix strace was sent to Linux kernel
mailing list in
2016](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20160921152946.GA24210@dhcp22.suse.cz)
but it has not been accepted, you can read the entire discussion to
get the idea why.  Nonetheless, I applied this patch to my local
[Linux kernel tree for Raspberry
Pi](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux) against rpi-5.6.y branch and
after rebuilding and replacing the kernel on Raspberry Pi `strace -f ./strace-test` doesn't get stuck any more. Linux source code has
changed a bit since 2016 and the patch doesn't apply cleanly. FWIW,
the full patch I applied is:

```
diff --git a/kernel/fork.c b/kernel/fork.c
index 60a1295..c26aaa1 100644
--- a/kernel/fork.c
+++ b/kernel/fork.c
@@ -1224,7 +1224,7 @@ struct mm_struct *mm_access(struct task_struct *task, unsigned int mode)
        struct mm_struct *mm;
        int err;

-       err =  mutex_lock_killable(&task->signal->cred_guard_mutex);
+       err =  mutex_lock_interruptible(&task->signal->cred_guard_mutex);
        if (err)
                return ERR_PTR(err);

diff --git a/kernel/signal.c b/kernel/signal.c
index 9ad8dea..ea7c7b5 100644
--- a/kernel/signal.c
+++ b/kernel/signal.c
@@ -108,6 +108,10 @@ static bool sig_ignored(struct task_struct *t, int sig, bool force)
        if (sigismember(&t->blocked, sig) || sigismember(&t->real_blocked, sig))
                return false;

+       /* Do not ignore signals sent from child to the parent */
+       if (current->ptrace && current->parent == t)
+               return 0;
+
        /*
         * Tracers may want to know about even ignored signal unless it
         * is SIGKILL which can't be reported anyway but can be ignored
```

Comment: Thanks @Arkadiusz! Where can i find some docs on how to build and patch a linux kernel for raspberry?? I am just starting with linux and lower level programming, just built my first linux kernel module :)

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md

Comment: Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I'm reading it again, and I am wondering why there isn't a youtube video with this troubleshoot. It would be so intriguing, insightful, and such a good learning experience for all the curious ones :)